# Compound CSS in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I want to get a page action when the HTML contains the word "promotional" or when there is a "submit" button. How do I modify the code below? How do i modify the compound css part?

This is a Google's example with a page containing a video. Thanks :)

```
var rule2 = {
    conditions: [
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          css: ["video"]
      })
    ],
    actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
};
```

Comment: I don't think matching based on a contained word is possible.

Comment: Inspect that submit button in devtools and use the corresponding selector. Could be something like `input[type='submit']` but this will match a lot of pages.